# Can some one explain what's going on here? const {a={}}=b

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain the difference between

```
const {a={}}=b
```

and

```
let a={}
a=b
```

It works fine on `const {a={}}=b` but only empty object returns on the second one.

Comment: Read object destructuring you may get what you looking for. And improve the question a little bit it's confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first snippet uses destructuring. It tries to take the `a` property out of the value in `b`. If no such property exists, `a` defaults to the empty object.

More verbosely

```
const {a={}}=b
```

is like

```
const a =
  b.a === undefined
  ? {}
  : b.a;
```

or

```
let a;
if (b.a === undefined) {
  a = {};
} else {
  a = b.a;
}
```

Your second snippet

```
let a={}
a=b
```

is completely different. It creates a single object, then discards it and reassigns `a` to whatever `b` contains.